# Placeholder templates with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, formatting

I need a function like

```sql
SELECT vformat('Hello %%! Bye %%...', array['John','Maria'], '%%');
-- 'Hello John! Bye Maria...'
```

Supplying a string with placeholders (a template), and corresponding inputs into a vector, it returns a text. The "placeholder mark" is a free string.

I can't use the pg9.1 format (like sprintf) function, because it does not allow other mark than '%' (see ex. [Python formatter](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings)) and not allow array parameter (see ex. [vsprintf](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php)). 
The SIMPLEST solution with PostgreSQL 9.0 (I think 8.4+) is

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION array_zipper_string(anyarray,anyarray) RETURNS text AS $$ 
  -- use with bigger array at left
  SELECT string_agg(t.val||coalesce($2[t.idx],''),'')  
  FROM  (SELECT generate_subscripts($1, 1) AS idx, unnest($1) AS val) AS t;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;

CREATE FUNCTION tpl_positional(text,anyarray,varchar DEFAULT '%%') 
RETURNS text AS $$ 
  SELECT array_zipper_string(string_to_array($1,$3),$2);
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
CREATE FUNCTION tpl_positional(
   text, text, varchar DEFAULT '%%',varchar DEFAULT '|' 
) RETURNS text AS $$ 
  SELECT tpl_positional($1,string_to_array($2,$4),$3);
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;

-- TESTING:
SELECT tpl_positional('Hello %%! Bye %%...', 'John|Maria');
SELECT tpl_positional('Hello %%!',array['John']);
```

There are  well-knowed (open source) *function* or *library* for do the same?

PS: that do this and also something more (!) ... My wishes list:

- open source from a standard library
- option to indexable placeholders, 'Hello %%{1}! Bye %%{2}...'
- option to use formatters, 'There are %%2d monkeys.' or 'There are %%{1|2d} monkeys.';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Python's formatting function does what you need, wrap it via PL/Python, and use that. You'll need to:

```
CREATE LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

... which may require you to install an additional package containing the python language support or re-compile using `--with-python`, depending on how you installed Pg or the packages you're using. For me using the Fedora 17 packages it was `yum install postgresql-plpython`.

You'll need a signature like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_format(formatstr text, placeholder text, args VARIADIC text) RETURNS text LANGUAGE 'plpythonu' IMMUTABLE AS $$
 .... body here ....
 $$;
```

Note the usage `plpython`**u**. Here **u** means "untrusted", ie "has no security model". Code running in untrusted languages can't be restricted, so the server only permits the superuser to create functions in such languages. They must be written so that they can't be tricked into doing things other than the author intended if the database is exposed to less-trusted users.

Unfortunately the procedural languages' handling of arrays was, last I checked, less than wonderful. See the depesz article at the bottom of this post, and its comments. It's workable, just clumsier than would be nice.

If Python's format functionality *doesn't* do what you want, consider Perl. PL/Perl is very popular, partly because unlike Python it has a security model and there's a "trusted" version of `plperl`. I'll be very surprised if you can't find a suitable CPAN module to do what you want. The function signature would be much the same, just with `plperl`.

See this [excellent-as-usual depesz article on plperl and sprintf](http://www.depesz.com/2008/08/01/writing-sprintf-and-overcoming-limitations-in-plperl/).

Comment: Hum... "non standard" PG languages, that need install an additional package... Ok, it is a possibility (perhaps not for may hosting). *THANKS* to remember here, and about the specific link. I use Perl for another tasks, and like Python. Another problem/question in the case of simplest functions, like my `tpl_positional()` above: when running with pure SQL or PL/pgSQL (the PG-standards), they are fasted? How much (benchmark equivalent functions)?

Comment: @PeterKrauss `PL/Perl` and `PL/Python` are part of the core server. However, they are often separated into optional modules by packagers and distributors so the main `postgresql` package doesn't have to depend on Perl and Python. Any decent host will offer `plperlu`; many will *not* offer the untrusted versions for obvious reasons.

Comment: @PeterKrauss I don't know what you're asking re the second part of your question. Are you asking how well the PLs perform vs built-in C functions? If so: benchmark and see, it depends on the PL, your workload, your OS, your Pg version, the version of Python/perl/etc, the exact function you're comparing, etc. Best results will probably be obtained by wrapping a `C` formatting library with a PostgreSQL C extension library, but you almost certainly won't be able to do that in a hosted environment.

Answer (score 10):

PostgreSQL FORMAT() function formats arguments based on a format string.

If you have worked with C programming language, you will find that the FORMAT() function is similar to the sprintf() function.

```
SELECT FORMAT('Hello, %s','PostgreSQL');

      format
-------------------
 Hello, PostgreSQL
(1 row)
```

For details, see http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-format/

Comment: Can PostgreSQL do literal string interpolation ?

Such as:  

name = "Tom"
print(f"His name is {name}.")

Answer (score 1):

Other possibility is using *orafce* http://postgres.cz/wiki/Oracle_functionality_%28en%29 - functions from schema ''PLVsubst'' does exactly what you want. Orafce is in redhat, centos repositories, but it is not enabled on any hosting usually.

Comment: Are you perhaps referring to the function `utl_file.putf()`, that is a formatter like the standard C sprintf()... Another one? About `putf()`, it is the same as the pg9.1 format() function; having the problems that I already  described. PS: the site *postgres.cz* is great, I used his suggestions to solve many other little problems.

Comment: There is issue in one kind of variadic functions in pg - http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-bugs/2012-09/msg00011.php - but I though function "string" - select **plvsubst.string('My name is %s %s', ARRAY['Pavel','Stěhule'])**;